# How can I get an img as a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There seems to be a problem with my img as button. They don't move together but separately. And its not just the img that is shown but also the button itself and I just want the img to be the button. I tried to make it a background img but nothing really worked.

I also want the button to move to the back of the page and don't take up any space. When I use z-index: -1; the function of button disappears and it no longer works as a button. How can I do this with different code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<div class="omheen">
<div>
<audio id="audioContainer">
 <source src="spraakbericht.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div id="memo">
 <button  id="play" onclick="playMp3()" type="button">
 <img class="memo" src="messages-05.png"/>
</div>
</button>
 <button id="pause" onclick="pauseMp3()" type="button">Pause Mp3</button> 

</div>
</div>

<script>
 const audioContainer = document.getElementById("audioContainer"); 

 function playMp3() { 
  audioContainer.play(); 
} 

function pauseMp3() { 
 audioContainer.pause(); 
} 


</script>

<script>
 var play = document.getElementById("play");
 var pause = document.getElementById("play");
 play.innerHTML = '<img src="\messages-05.png" />';
 pause.innerHTML = '<img src="\messages-05.png" />';
</script>   





</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In that case, why don't you just use an image instead of a button?

Comment: If you want image to behave like button (respond on click) you should make a JS listener on click. However, you've set "onclick" on button while wanting image to be clicked

Answer (score 1):

With the button element in html5 you can put images in between the tags. Also make sure to set the type attribute with button tags as different browsers use different default types for the button element. In order for the button to not take any space you have to set display to none or set it's position to absolute. The z-index level could not be affected because the elements are positioned as static.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing the img tag inside the button tag. For example:

```
<button id="test><img src="/img/ex.png" alt="Test img"/></button>
```

Comment: I got it inside the tag right? But it doesn't really work

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<input type="image" src="messages-05.png">
```

more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

[update]
Your code looks a little mixed up. So I tried to clean it up a little to show the use of my suggestion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="omheen">
 <div>
  <audio id="audioContainer">
   <source src="spraakbericht.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
 </div>
 <div id="memo">
  <input type="image" id="playButton" src="messages-05.png" onclick="playMp3();">
  <input type="image" id="pauseButton" src="messages-05.png" onclick="pauseMp3();">
 </div>
</div>

<script>
 const audioContainer = document.getElementById("audioContainer");
 var playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");
 var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton"); 

 function playMp3() { 
  audioContainer.play(); 
 } 

 function pauseMp3() { 
  audioContainer.pause(); 
 } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the functions you can easily change the images for your buttons by changing the src-attribute of playButton and pauseButton.

Make sure, the image is in the same folder as the html-file.

Comment: Did you replace the div with id memo (closing tags of div and button are mixed up btw.) with the input tag? Maybe it disappears because of some css that we don't know about since you don't show it here?